# How to change the group of a file generated by my python codes on Linux server?

Tags: linux, filesystems, python, user-accounts, user-groups

I belong to multiple groups (AAA, BBB, CCC, and etc.) on a Linux server. And I wrote a python code that generates a file on the server. When generated, this file belongs to group AAA, by default. But I hope the file belong to group BBB. Do I have to manually use the "chgrp" command on this file to change its group, after I run the codes? Is there a way to automatically do it so whenever I run this code, the generated file always belong to group BBB?

I've tried to "run the python codes as a member of group BBB", by switching my current group to BBB - by doing `newgrp BBB` and then run the codes. But it didn't work and the generated file still belong to group AAA.

Please kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Does the parent directory happen to have the 'setgid' flag set? (i.e. `rws` permissions rather than the usual rwx)

Comment: Hi @user1686, thanks for your reply! I don't know the answer to your question though. Is there a command that I can use to find out? I have Googled around but no luck so far.

Comment: Run `ls -ld` on the directory.

Comment: Hi @user1686, I did `ls -ld` and saw the usual `rwx`, not `rws`. What does this imply? Thanks again and sorry for the late reponse.